# Xcode 7 beta swift app crashes on runtime with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following code crashing.

```
class PersonFactory {
  class var build: PersonInterface {
    get {
      return Person()
    }
  }
}

class Person: PersonInterface {
  var age: Int = 0

  func say(message: String) {
    print(message)
  }
}

protocol PersonInterface: class {
  var age: Int { get set }

  func say(message: String)
}
```

It crashes when I run the following line from the [view controller](https://github.com/exchangegroup/ProtocolCrashDemo/blob/master/InterfaceCrashDemo/ViewController.swift):

```
PersonFactory.build.say("hello")
```

Crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the following line `var age: Int = 0`. The problem appears in Xcode 7 beta 4 (7A165t).

Note that **the code does NOT crash in the Playground**, only when it is called from the app. Here is the demo app: https://github.com/exchangegroup/ProtocolCrashDemo

**Note**: The code defining PersonFactory, Person and PersonInterface should be in a **separate file** for it to crash.

Looks like a Swift 2.0 bug? I filed a bug report to Apple.

### Update

The problem has been fixed in Xcode 7.0 beta 5.

Comment: Try putting the code in the same source file as the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this crash by doing this:

```
import Foundation

class PersonFactory<T: PersonInterface> {
    class var build: T {
        return T()
    }
}

class Person: PersonInterface {
    var age: Int

    required init() {
        age = 0
    }

    func say(message: String) {
        print(message)
    }
}

protocol PersonInterface {
    init()

    var age: Int { get set }

    func say(message: String)
}

let person: Person = PersonFactory.build
person.say("hello")
```

Comment: By the way, what is the `<T:` signify? What's the technical term for it? Is it an ArrayList? I'm a Java person learning Swift, and I've been wanting to learn about how it works, what it's used for, etc. but couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: I know that longform of an array is `Array<T>`, but after a class declaration?

Comment: In Swift T is a generic

Answer (score 1):

Bug most likely, as I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and it looks fine.  [image]

Comment: Thanks, the code runs without problems in the Playground for me as well in Xcode 7 but crashes in iOS app.

Comment: Any way something's not being initialized when you run in the simulator? If there are any IBOutlets, sometimes leftover links can throw an `exc_bad_access`. They're the most annoying of all errors.

Comment: Good point, I tried creating a new app with just this code to isolated the case, here is the view controller https://github.com/exchangegroup/ProtocolCrashDemo/blob/master/InterfaceCrashDemo/ViewController.swift